# Display git tag (version) on my app's login page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, version-control

I want to display the current git tag on my app's login page,
Its built using react.
Im trying to use the 'git-rev-sync' library to do this.
but it doesnt seem to work on the client side because I keep getting errors like 
'cannot find module 'children process', it works on the server side where Im able to console.log and print the tag
anyone know how to achieve this? Open to any solutions with any library

```
import version from 'git-rev-sync'
...
class Login extends Component {
...
render ()
...
return (
<div> my version: {version.tag()} </div>
) }

Thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use git-revision-webpack-plugin which creates a VERSION file (among other files) in the dist folder, and then I read the file from my client side react app:
add this to your webpack.js:

```
const GitRevisionPlugin = require('git-revision-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new GitRevisionPlugin({
      lightweightTags: true //I added this to get the tags as well
    })
  ]
}
```

then my client side looks like this:

```
  const [revision, setRevision] = useState('')

  const fetchRevision = async () => {
    let result = await fetch('/dist/VERSION')
    let txt = await result.text()
    txt = txt.replace(/^(.*?)(?:\-.*)?$/, '$1') //I only care for the tag.
    setRevision(txt)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRevision()
  }, [])
```

and then you can render the revision

One thing to notice, depending on your server, you may need to tell it to serve this VERSION file as is, so for example in express, you might find you need this:

```
server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (/^\/dist\/*/.test(req.originalUrl)) {
    const relative = req.originalUrl.replace(/\/dist(\/.*)/, '$1')
    const filename = path.join(compiler.outputPath, relative)
    compiler.outputFileSystem.readFile(filename, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err)
      }
      res.send(result)
      res.end()
    })
  }
  ...
})
```

Hope this helps for future use.

Answer (score -1):

If you used `create-react-app@0.2.3 >` to generate your app.

create-react-app scripts use environment variables that start with the `REACT_APP_` symbol in the root .env file. [create-react-app - Adding custom environment variables](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) is a good place to dig into the details.

or just include the following in your .env file.

#### .env

`REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version`

and access it on your react login component by referring to `{process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION}`

Comment: While this is great answer how to show the `package.json` version, this does not answer the question about showing the `git tag` version.